# Firebase updating with node.js - do I need to await?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, backend

**Scenario:**

Some code is listening on collection A for changes. When one occurs, it does some calculation and updates collection B.

Time between changes in A: 20-50ms.
Time for actual calculation: 20-30ms.
Time for roundtrip sending updates to firebase: 250-300ms.

So the code is something like this:

```
const runUpdates = async (snapshot) => {
  const inputData = snapshot && snapshot.exists() && snapshot.val() || undefined
  if (inputData) {
    const calculatedData = calculateStuff(inputData)
    await firebase.database().ref().update({ 'collectionB': calculatedData })
  }
}

firebase.database().ref('collectionA').on('value', runUpdates)
```

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database.

**Actual question:**

Does the firebase package (using local cache or any other means necessary) assure that the updates will be done in firebase in the same order that I have done them in my code or do I need to `await` for every update to finish before I can move on to my next computation & update?

**More details:**

There is a mechanism in place for cases when there is a trigger event but the calculation/update is not yet finished. I'm porpusfully ignoring that or clarity.

I'm trying to improve this code and it seems that in many cases the calculation is relatively short, but then I need to wait for the response from firebase to start the next calculation.

I've been told that firebase has a local cache (server-side) and that my firebase update command actually updates that locally (and therefore is "immediate") and then works to propagate the change to firebase itself. Any sequential updates would also be propagated, while the sequence is assured.

(Needless to say, I tried looking around for this info in the docs etc)

Comment: Which Firebase product are you using (Realtime Database? Firestore?)?  It might also help if you showed more code that actually worked with said product, and explain the specific behavior of the series of calls that you're working with.

Comment: @DougStevenson - I'm using Realtime Database (added in the question too). About the actuall code, I will try and explain a bit better what is going on. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries to Realtime Database are pipelined over a single socket connection.  The results will be delivered in the order that the queries were issued.

If you need to know when the results of write have been fully committed to the server, you will need to pay attention to the promise returned by `update()`.  That promise will become fulfilled only after the write completes on the server, and not when changes are available just locally.

Whether your use `await` or `then` on that promise doesn't really matter.  Either way, you will know the result of the update.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I can find the relevant docs for this?

Comment: is there a reason why you shouldn't await on an `update` operation ?

Comment: @Eitank My opinion is that you should think of it in the opposite direction.  Only write code to pay attention to the result of the promise if you intend to do something with it.  If you don't need the result, then adding additional code is not helpful, and potentially confusing the reader of that code.

Comment: @DougStevenson so basically if i am not doing anything else if it fails other than logging it, then i shouldn't await on the promise of the update? if i understand your answer.

Comment: @DougStevenson also, making sure that your answer about the `update` is the same for `set` right ?

Comment: @Eitank It's the same for all functions that return a promise.  Don't write unnecessary code.  Only use await if you have a specific reason to do so.